# Why isn't this jquery-driven table sort working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Javascript which fetches lines from a web API which serves data in pages.

In partial pseudocode, this is:

```
for each page
    ajax (url+pageid, function (result)
    {
        for each row  of data
            tbody_domnode .appendChild (create_row (row));

        sort_table (tbody_domnode, sort_func);
    }

 function create_row (row)
 {
      var tr = document .createElement ('tr');
      tr .timestamp = row .timestamp;         // miliseconds in UNIX epoch
      tr .title = tr .timestamp;              // for debugging
      ...
      return tr;
 }
```

That much works fine, except for sort_table, which is code I've adapted from another question here. I'm new to jQuery so there are a couple of aspects of it which I don't understand.

In any case, it *almost* works, but by hovering the mouse over the table rows, some of the timestamps (as shown by the title element) are out of order. Here's the sort code in full.

```
function sort_table_rows (tbody, sort_function)
{
    var rows = $("tr", tbody);

    rows .sort (sort_function);

    rows .each (function (index, row)
    {
        $(rows) .append (row);
    });
}

function sort_func (a, b)
{
    return a .timestamp - b .timestamp;
}
```

Am I using the jQuery functions correctly to sort the tr nodes within tbody_domnode? Or should I look elsewhere for the bug?

Comment: Lots wrong with that code; hard to know where to start. :)  jQuery objects (like `rows` variable) aren't really arrays in any useful sense.  So sorting them like that is not feasible.  Maybe it works, probably not.  Then near the end when you want to append a jQuery object, you can just append the whole thing, no need to loop.  In jQuery a jQuery object is a jQuery object, whether it contains one element or many.  But in this case, you are basically appending the rows back to themselves, which is all sorts of crazy.

Comment: Oh....kay. Thanks. Know an example of The Right Way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most new code today would use some sort of data binding framework like AngularJs to keep the code simpler, or even a simple [templating](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+template) solution.

If you're stuck with just jQuery, rather than try to sort the html, it is simpler to just work with the data and completely recreate the html as-needed.  You can attach data to jQuery elements using `.data('key', value)` where value can be any object or array.

So at the beginning you could do`$(tbody_domnode).data('serverData', result)`.  Then, sort the data using your sort function whenever needed, and completely replace the tbody contents whenever you want to show the results:

```
function paintRows(tbody)
{
  var $tbody = $(tbody);
  $tbody.remove('tr');
  var data = $tbody.data('serverData');

  $.each(data, function(index, rowData) {
    ...create and add the row to the tbody
  });
}
```